# Calling a method in a controller defined in a directive from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a way to call a method in a controller defined in a directive from a global function. I was able to successfully do this defining the controller in the module and declaring the controller using ng-controller in a normal html element. Then I get the controller and the scope from the javascript function like this:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    var googleLoginControllerElement = document.getElementById('googlelogin');
    var ctrlScope = angular.element(googleLoginControllerElement).scope();
    var controller = angular.element(googleLoginControllerElement).controller();

    ctrlScope.$apply(function() {
        controller.signinCallBack(authResult);
    });
}
```

but when I moved the definition of the controller to the definition of a directive I was not able to find a way to do this (new code after moving the controller definition to a directive):

```
var googleLogin = angular.module('GoogleLogin', []);

googleLogin.directive('googleLogin', function() {
    return {

    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function() {
    // Initialize google login api
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); 
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();

         /*
         * 1: not logged in.
         * 2: logged in.
         * 3: login failed.
         * 4: logout failed.
         */
         this.state = 1;

         this.signinCallBack = function(authResult) {
         if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
             console.log('authResult: ' + JSON.stringify(authResult));
             this.state = 2;
         } else if (authResult.error === "user_signed_out") {
             console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
                 this.state = 1;
         }
        };

        this.logout = function() {
            try {
                gapi.auth.signOut();
                this.state = 1;
             } catch(e) {
                 this.state = 4;
             }
        };

        this.isLoggedIn = function() {
            return this.state == 2;
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'googleLoginCtrl',
    templateUrl: '../templates/google_login.html'
};
});
```

In my html I use the directive like this:

```
<google-login></google-login>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to call the function from a global function?

Comment: And where is googleLoginCtrl?

Comment: @Joao, the global function is called by the oauth login workflow. From there I want to pass the control flow to my angular module providing the result of the oath authentication (the authResult variable in my code) so that my angular module keeps track of the login state.

Comment: @Sergey, that is the alias for the controller. I use it to reference it from my template (google_login.html). I didn't include the code from the template because it's not relevant to the problem at hand, but I can do so if it helps you better understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Cristobal you can (should?) put your login workflow inside an angular directive and then it will all be within the angular world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify the scope which your directive must use.

Refer this doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

**Edit : **

I gave an id to your element so that I can get access to it.

```
<google-login id="mybtn"></google-login>
```

& Changed your global function as .

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
//  alert('I came here also inside callback global');

  var googleLoginControllerElement = document.getElementById('mybtn');
  var ctrlScope = angular.element(googleLoginControllerElement).scope();

 ctrlScope.$apply(function() {
      ctrlScope.googleLoginCtrl.signinCallBack(authResult);
     });

  //      ctrlScope.googleLoginCtrl.signinCallBack(authResult);
  //alert('I came here also inside callback global end');

}
```

I was trying ctrlScope.controller but oversaw that a name was given to it.

Comment: I was not able to find anything I could use to solve my problem in the link you provided. Do you think you could provide an example using code?

Comment: Can u create a plunkr or js fiddle ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BXAwmP4bIdPwiYVncWLx

The idea would be to call the method signinCallback(authResult) in the GoogleLogin module from the global function signinCallback(authResult) in google_login.js

Comment: worked after wrapping the call to the controller in a function passed to ctrlScope.$apply() like this:  ctrlScope.$apply(function() {
  ctrlScope.googleLoginCtrl.signinCallBack(authResult);
 });
 See the first fragment of code in my question. Please edit the answer with this fix before I accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Cristobal. Please check the edit. ( but the original one worked in your fiddle.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (i'm not sure if it will work, let me know):

```
window.globalSigninCallBack = this.signinCallBack;
```

inside of your directive:

```
googleLogin.directive('googleLogin', function() {
    return {

    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function() {
    // Initialize google login api
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();

         /*
         * 1: not logged in.
         * 2: logged in.
         * 3: login failed.
         * 4: logout failed.
         */
         this.state = 1;

         this.signinCallBack = function(authResult) {
         if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
             console.log('authResult: ' + JSON.stringify(authResult));
             this.state = 2;
         } else if (authResult.error === "user_signed_out") {
             console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
                 this.state = 1;
         }
        };

        window.globalSigninCallBack = this.signinCallBack;

        this.logout = function() {
            try {
                gapi.auth.signOut();
                this.state = 1;
             } catch(e) {
                 this.state = 4;
             }
        };

        this.isLoggedIn = function() {
            return this.state == 2;
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'googleLoginCtrl',
    templateUrl: '../templates/google_login.html'
};
});
```

then later in the code call:

```
window.globalSigninCallBack(authResult);
```

but this is very hacky workaround and i would never use this in my code:)

Comment: I gave this a try. It doesn't work calling window directly. You have to import the $window service and call $window.globalSigninCallBack = this.signinCallBack; This approach didn't work for me. I stepped with the debugger through the instructions and everything seems fine, but the bindings don't get updated. I tried calling $apply in different places but it was undefined.

Comment: @Cristobal i setup a small example in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0UnCkFpJslDSAj2mDKq4?p=preview

Comment: I also got that working, but I was not able to change the state of the controller. For example, based on your example, I was not able to change the value of $scope.name and see the effect in the page.