# Calling a function defined in a directive's scope from a controller

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT**: I created a Plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/yuvtrPs3csAQZW7OF06O

I'm not sure if this has anything to do, but I noticed the console's log shows:

> Event tracked Multipane Show Preview Toolbar undefined undefined

---

Premise: I'm creating a new question following the "probably forgotten" question at the link:

> [AngularJS: How do I call a function defined in a directive's scope from a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197586/angularjs-how-do-i-call-a-function-defined-in-a-directives-scope-from-a-contro)

Since I got one answer there, I informed him of the new question in case he wants to complete his answer here.
Also, I know there are similar questions, but I can't find a solution suitable for my case.

I need to call a function which belongs to the $scope of a ng-directive used in my Angular application.
Following the tutorial at:

> http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

I set up the following code as example.

Let's say the directive is defined like this: (concretely the directive -- simplified here -- is the one defined by the plugin: www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2/#angularjs )

**Note**: there is **not** parent-child relation between the directive and the controller which I want to make access the directive's controller's function. This is why I use **$rootScope**

```
.directive('my-directive', ['$document', '$timeout', '$rootScope', function ($document, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            // ....
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

            var myFunction= function () {
                // do something...
            };

            $scope.$on('openLanguageSelectionPopup', function (){
                console.log("event triggered"); // NOT triggered!
                myFunction();  
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I need to call **myFunction** from my controller (called **mainController**) which is the controller of the view where my directive is placed. I defined it as:

```
.controller('mainController',
function ($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.$emit('openLanguageSelectionPopup'); 
    // this is event should be received by any $rootScope.$on(...) in ANY controller
})
```

I modified the directive's controller itself but unsuccessfully

In fact the event (**openLanguageSelectionPopup**) is not triggered (console.log is not printed).
I am also sure that both the $on and the $emit are reached at some point (I tried with console.log(...) ).

I understand the problem may be in directive's scope definition as proposed as solution in the following answer:

> [Calling a method in a controller defined in a directive from a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018812/calling-a-method-in-a-controller-defined-in-a-directive-from-a-javascript-functi)

However, if this is the problem, I can't understand what the accepted answer can bring to my specific case.

**Also, I don't understand where I should put $rootScope**: in the directive's controller function or in the directive's definition function (in my example I added it in both).

Comment: You are listening to `'closeLanguageSelectionPopup'` in your directives controller instead of `'openLanguageSelectionPopup'`. Does this change anythong?

Comment: I apologize. Indeed I've two different listeners but If I figure out how to solve for one, I'll solve for both. question edited  (maybe there's a way to analize which controllers are actually able to receive the specific event?)

Comment: Shouldn't you use $rootScope.$broadcast because emit goes up in the scope tree so it reaches rootScope in the end but you already start it at the rootScope.

you can use $scope.$emit however to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: please try `$broadcast` instead of `$emit`, as `$broadcast` does channels down to your child scopes, where it should reach the scope of your directive

Comment: in my case $broadcast and $emit should be equivalent when used with $rootScope (according to the mentioned tutorial).
However I tried with $broadcast as well. same result

Comment: @dragonmnl Is it possible for you to construct a simple plunkr of jsfinddle ?

Comment: @BobThomas I just created it: http://plnkr.co/edit/yuvtrPs3csAQZW7OF06O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You emit and broadcast your stuff in the controller.
But the directive doesn't exist.

Atleast i think that's happening.
Because if i wrap your broadcast in a timeout they receive it.

Also your plunkr is missing somethings

You forgot to add the script to the index.html
And you call your directive in the html like this  but it should be

Comment: you are right. for some reason the plunkr wasn't saved.
Can you please check out my plunkr again? Now I don't understand why the directive itself doesn't render (I admit it's the first time I try to write one directive).
Also, any idea how to overcome the "it doesn't exist" issue?
thanks again

Comment: also, I just tried on my own to add a $timeout but I see no difference (feel free to edit the Plunkr)

Comment: Its because you still have this in your main.html
 <myDirective></myDirective> it should be <my-directive></my-directive>

Comment: yes, I just noticed it.
any idea about the timeout? (how to avoid it..like "wait until the directive is loaded")

Comment: Hmm can't think of a clean way to do it.
I never had this problem before

Comment: Hmm maybe this a fun solution.
Make the directive broadcast or emit an event like durpLoaded and then let the controller listen on that and fire his own event

Comment: yes, it sounds kind of fun workaround but it may work (I will try it later). thank you :-)